# REST - GET-Respone with temporary uploaded File

Tags: rest

I know that the title is not that correct, but i don't know how to name this problem...

Currently I'm trying to design my first REST-API for a conversion-service. Therefore the user has an input file which is given to the server and gets back the converted file.

The current problem I've got is, that the converted file should be accessed with a simple GET /conversionservice/my/url. However it is not possible to upload the input file within GET-Request. A POST would be necessary (am I right?), but POST isn't cacheable.

Now my question is, what's the right way to design this? I know that it could be possible to upload the input file before to the server and then access it with my GET-Request, but those input files could be everything!

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A POST request is actually needed for a file upload. The fact that it is not cachable should not bother the service because how could any intermediaries (the browser, the server, proxy etc) know about the content of the file. If you need cachability, you would have to implement it yourself probably with a hash (md5, sha1 etc) of the uploaded file. This would keep you from having to perform the actual conversion twice, but you would have to hash each file that was uploaded which would slow you down for a "cache miss".

The only other way I could think of to solve the problem would be to require the user to pass in an accessible url to the file in the query string, then you could handle GET requests, but your users would have to make the file accessible over the internet. This would allow caching but limit the usability.

Perhaps a hybrid approach would be possible where you accepted a POST for a file upload and a GET for a url, this would increase the complexity of the service but maximize usability.

Also, you should look into what caches you are interested in leveraging as a lot of them have limits on the size of a cache entry meaning if the file is sufficiently large it would not cache anyway.

In the end, I would advise you to stick to the standards already established. Accept the POST request for the file upload and if you are interested in speeding up the user experience maybe make the upload persist, this would allow the user to upload a file once and download it in many different formats.

Answer (score 1):

You sequence of events can be as follows:

1. Upload your file/files using POST. For immediate response, you can return required information using your own headers. (It should return document key to access the file for future use.)
2. Then you can use GET for further operations using the above mentioned document key as a query string.